# How to run a plugin as the first task when a mvn command (ex: mvn clean install) is given in command line?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

In Maven project. I want to have pom.xml.template (the original pom.xml but having the version values as parameters) and a versions.properties file (where I have the value for the versions) and I need to generate a pom.xml file when user gives mvn clean or mvn install or any similar command.

If I create a plugin for it. When and where can I trigger that plugin so that the first action for any command would be executing my custom plugin.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? It seems like you might be interested in the [Maven Versions plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/)

Comment: Why are you trying to have versions in a separate file?

Comment: Versions externalized into a properties file does not make sense in Maven. If you like to have the version of your artifacts more flexible I can recommand: http://maven.apache.org/maven-ci-friendly.html

Comment: Also check this out: https://dzone.com/articles/why-i-never-use-maven-release

Comment: The reason for going with the proposed approach is that we need to change the version and also few properties in the pom.xml according to the branch it is in. Ex: if Release branch 1.0-Release09/12/2017 and if feature branch 1.0-SNAPSHOT. (Just as an example, decision yet to be taken on versioning for branch).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Properties Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/read-project-properties-mojo.html)